# How to set Activity-Class es for each page of ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i want to set different pages for ViewPager from class. for example:
i have 4 activity A + B + C and D.
A include my ViewPager.
B +C + D are different pages that must be shown in ViewPager.(each of them have different contex)
my question is that, how can i recognize these pages into ViewPager?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add but better way is that you will create a activity and your four activity should be child fragment of the same .
In short your all activity should be fragments jst load the fregment when you swipe viewpage indicater

sample code for adapter

//User adapter according condition
       final FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentChildPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

```
       //final FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentChildPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));

    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) v.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);

  //Adapter  

  class FragmentChildPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        IconPagerAdapter {
    public FragmentChildPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:


                          //first fregment
            break;
        case 1:

            //Second fregment
             break;
        case 2:
            //third fragment
              break;
             case 3:
            //Forth fragment
              break;
        }

        return fragment;

    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    /*@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();

    }*/
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return CONTENT.length;
        return CONTENT.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int position) {

        return (Integer) Icon.get(position % CONTENT.size()); 

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. i am starter, so i have some questions about your answer.i wish you gave me compelete class and xml code.i have lots of problemsthanks